# Is there a unique ID for each iPhone / iPod Touch?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, privacy

Is there a unique ID like the mac address for each iPhone / iPod Touch?

Do I have to ask the user for permissions to transmit such a unique id?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, <strike>you can get it using UIDevice's uniqueIdentifier property:</strike>

> A unique device identifier is a hash value composed from various hardware identifiers such as the device’s serial number. It is guaranteed to be unique for every device but cannot publically be tied to a user account. You can use it, for example, to store high scores for a game in a central server or to control access to registered products. The unique device identifier is sometimes referred to by its abbreviation UDID.

**Edit:** uniqueIdentifier property is deprecated in iOS5 and you should not use it now. As an alternative you can generate your own unique ID (for example check [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6993325/137350)).

Also in iOS6 Apple added 2 new methods to get unique identifier (as an instance of [NSUUID](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUUID_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class):

**UIDevice -identifierForVendor**:

> The value of this property is the same for apps that come from the
> same vendor running on the same device. A different value is returned
> for apps onthe same device that come from different vendors, and for
> apps on different devices regardles of vendor.

**ASIdentifierManager  -advertisingIdentifier**:

> Unlike the identifierForVendor property of the UIDevice, the same
> value is returned to all vendors. This identifier may change—for
> example, if the user erases the device—so you should not cache it.

Comment: thanks [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier] works great !

Comment: This is deprecated. [See related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396187/method-uidevice-currentdevice-uniqueidentifier-is-not-allowed-any-more-i-ne)