# iOS deprecated UDID, replacement?

Tags: ios, objective-c, identifier

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UIDevice uniqueIdentifier Deprecated - What To Do Now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993325/uidevice-uniqueidentifier-deprecated-what-to-do-now)

According to articles in recent time, the `UDID identifier` will be deprecated since iOS 5 and maybe removed in future releases

What are we supposed to use then?

info:
http://www.tuaw.com/2011/08/19/ios-5-deprecates-udid-as-identifier-for-developers-but-its-not/
http://appadvice.com/appnn/2011/08/apple-deprecates-udid-access-will-prevent-creepy-developers-from-tracking-you

Comment: @jtbandes - See the duplicate question I've linked to.  Since then, this has been asked at least twice.