# No Access to udid

Tags: ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UIDevice uniqueIdentifier Deprecated - What To Do Now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993325/uidevice-uniqueidentifier-deprecated-what-to-do-now)

I have learnt that apple is going to remove the access of udid from the system in iOS5.For All of us who rely so much on this,what would be the solution?Even ads and analytics would seize to work.Would there be a work around for that?Thanks for any answer

Comment: thats the 3rd question 2day asking the same thing and probably will ge the same answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple is ***NOT*** removing access to UDID, it's just [deprecating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation) it.

So, Apple doesn't want you to use it anymore, but they will not forbid it yet, they just strongly recommend using a new feature of iOS 5 that shouldn't be discussed here while under NDA. Compiler will give you a warning if you access udid, but it's still there and it works, so stop spreading panic.