# iOS 5 - No more UDID - How to keep some critical datas to identifiy the user even if app is deleted

Tags: iphone, ios, nsuserdefaults, uniqueidentifier, udid

I've just read on a blog that the UDID will not survive iOS 5. I use it as an identifier combined to an app ID I generate myself. Without that UDID, I will just have the App Identifier but as it is stored in the userDefaukts for the moment, it is deleted if the app is uninstalled.

How may I do to keep it safe even if the app is deleted from the iPhone ? I have to achieve this to ensure that I have at least one stable identifier, even if it's not the sole one I use to identify the user.

Comment: It's *deprecated*, not *removed*. Expect it to be removed by the time iOS 6 launches, though.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993325/uidevice-uniqueidentifier-deprecated-what-to-do-now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out, its designed specifically for this problem:
https://github.com/gekitz/UIDevice-with-UniqueIdentifier-for-iOS-5

Comment: if the user remove the app from the iPhone, update it from iTunes some days later and reinstall it, will the MAC-Adresse/Bundle identifier couple generate the same identifier than before ?

Comment: Honestly I dont know. I DO know that a lot of developers are using this moving forward, so I am sure that the community can answer that for you.