# ios 5 AWS SDK S3PutObjectRequest

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, ios5

I just updated my app to ios5 and the code below (that was working in 4x) is now not working
I thought it was because of the UUID but i changed that and the error stayed the same.  The error I am getting is below.  Any help is greatly appreciated -- thx

I setup some breakpoints and isolated the error and i think the error is with localPutObjectRequest but after looking at what that line does the error message does not make sense to me.

```
- (void) updateLocation:(CLLocation*)loc
{
    [progressView setProgress:5];
    [[LocationManager sharedLocationManager] setDelegate:nil];

    uploadPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@-%f.png", [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier], [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier], [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];

    S3PutObjectRequest *localPutObjectRequest = [[[S3PutObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:uploadPath inBucket:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"spotted-at"]] autorelease];


    localPutObjectRequest.data = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithData:imageData]);
    [localPutObjectRequest setDelegate:self];

    [[Constants s3] putObject:localPutObjectRequest];

}



2011-10-23 00:45:39.654 spotted.at[4131:707] -[UIButtonContent length]: unrecognized   selector sent to instance 0x2c0130
2011-10-23 00:45:39.656 spotted.at[4131:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButtonContent length]: unrecognized  selector sent to instance 0x2c0130'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x310868bf 0x3822b1e5 0x31089acb 0x31088945 0x30fe3680 0x330e42ef 0x330e4267 0x331d7e51    0x49041 0x4973d 0x352c05df 0x352bff81 0x352ba62f 0x3105ab31 0x3105a15f 0x31059381 0x30fdc4dd 0x30fdc3a5 0x33c0afed 0x3304e743 0x453b 0x3f74)
```

Comment: UIDevice `uniqueIdentifier` is deprecated in iOS 5.

Comment: Yes, but that is not the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Judging from your post, the error lies in

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]
```

The method UIDevice `uniqueIdentifier` is deprecated in iOS 5 and should not be called. From your code I cant really see what exactly you are trying to do but this post
[UIDevice uniqueIdentifier Deprecated - What To Do Now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993325/uidevice-uniqueidentifier-deprecated-what-to-do-now)

should be helpful in overcoming the deprecated method. You should change the deprecated calls and also use the ones listed in the post above. That should do the trick.

Comment: I tried that already, and it gave me the same error.  The issue is not w/ the upload path its w/ the local put object request.

Comment: but your local put object request is derived from upload path right?

Comment: Deprecated does not mean removed. The method still works fine and could not be the cause of the error.