# Retrieve iOS device identifier

Tags: iphone, ios, uniqueidentifier

Is there any way to get the iOS device identifier in iOS SDK?
I would like to access the identifier which is presented by the Xcode in **Organizer - Devices** section, something like: 21xb1fxef5x2052xec31x3xd3x48ex5e437xe593

Comment: Why do you want to get that identifier?

Comment: I need to uniquely identify the device

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/uniqueIdentifier):

> An alphanumeric string unique to each device based on various hardware
>   details. (read-only) (Deprecated in iOS 5.0. Use the
>   identifierForVendor property of this class or the
>   advertisingIdentifier property of the ASIdentifierManager class
>   instead, as appropriate, or use the UUID method of the NSUUID class to
>   create a UUID and write it to the user defaults database.)

Answer (score 12):

It looks like you still can access UDID under iOS 6, but **it is deprecated** since iOS 5.0 and you shouldn't use it (anyway you'll get warning about that)

```
[UIDevice currentDevice].uniqueIdentifier
```

If you need unique identifier you should rather use :

```
[UIDevice currentDevice].identifierForVendor
```

or if it is connected with some kind of advertisement then:

```
// from  AdSupport.framework
[ASIdentifierManager sharedManager].advertisingIdentifier
```

However those two new properties are available only under iOS >= 6.0, also advertisingIdentifier is not really unique (I'm getting many duplicates from that).

I suppose that you can do something like that if you wan't to support also iOS < 6:

```
UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
NSString *ident = nil;
if ([device respondsToSelector:SEL(identifierForVendor)]) {
    ident = [device.identifierForVendor UUIDString];
} else {
    ident = device.uniqueIdentifier;
}
```

but I'm not sure how apple will respond to that during review.

<strike>You can also use some 3rd party solution like [openUDID](https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID) or [secureUDID](http://www.secureudid.org)</strike>. Open and secure UDIDs are deprecated - use identifier for vendor/advertising.

---

Update

<strike>One more possibility is to use MAC address as a base for unique hash, for example you can use code from [ODIN1](http://code.google.com/p/odinmobile/wiki/ODIN1) - [source is here](http://odinmobile.googlecode.com/svn/Sample%20Code/iOS/trunk/)</strike>

As of iOS7 MAC address is no longer available. (one can read it but it'll be always same dummy address 02:00:00:00:00:00).

Comment: The property is Deprecated in iOS 5.0

Comment: yeah, sorry, at first I wrote uniqueIdentifier instead of identifierForVendor, but anyway I think it was quite obvious that something is wrong when I wrote that you shouldn't use uniqueIdentifier and in second line that you should use it ;)

Comment: SecureUDID is no longer supported by Crashlytics; they write: "We recommend using Apple's iOS 6 vendor and advertising identifiers instead.".

Comment: thanks, I updated my answer also with MAC address which is not available since iOS7

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString* identifier = nil;
if( [UIDevice instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(identifierForVendor)] ) {
  // iOS 6+
  identifier = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
} else {
  // before iOS 6, so just generate an identifier and store it
  identifier = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"identiferForVendor"];
  if( !identifier ) {
    CFUUIDRef uuid = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
    identifier = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, uuid);
    CFRelease(uuid);
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:identifier forKey:@"identifierForVendor"];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find unique device identifier as

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
+ (NSString *)uuid
{
    NSString *uuidString = nil;
    CFUUIDRef uuid = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
    if (uuid) {
        uuidString = (NSString *)CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, uuid);
        CFRelease(uuid);
    }
    return [uuidString autorelease];
}
```

It works 100%, even on simulators too...

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is.

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]
```

EDIT:
However this is deprecated in iOS 5. This identifier should no longer be used in iOS 5. Read [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894258/the-ios-5-changed-the-uniqueidentifier-code) post for more details.

Comment: This is deprecated in iOS 5 and applications using this will not be allowed into the App Store.