# Cocos2D - Start up errors with CLScoreServer

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, warnings, uniqueidentifier

Im getting 2 errors/warnings when im trying to build/run my app in the simulator, the error is in the SDK i guess.

File: CLScoreServerPost.m

```
'uniqueIdentifier' is deprecated (declared at /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIDevice.h:64)
```

and this one in CLScoreServerRequest.m

```
'uniqueIdentifier' is deprecated (declared at /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIDevice.h:64)
```

I've been trying to reinstall the templates ect ect ect and nothing works.
Some one know the problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says it right there:

> [uniqueIdentifier is deprecated](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html)

And so you should search for it on Google to come up with the [related Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993325/uidevice-uniqueidentifier-deprecated-what-to-do-now).

Deprecated means it should no longer be used, and it may be flagged as an error if you do use it depending on certain circumstances. My guess is that if your deployment target is set to iOS 5.0 and since iOS 5.0 deprecated that method, it's going to be an error when building an app that targets iOS 5. It's probably just a warning if you target iOS 4.x or earlier.

If you are calling that method, then don't. If that call is in a third party library, then contact the author of that library.

Answer (score 0):

Try rebooting your iPhone and computer. Then, after you run your app from Xcode and as it was running on your phone, stop the task. Then, re-open the app through the phone without Xcode running any task.

I did this and did not receive any further errors, and was able to open/close from the active app area (double-tap home button), and I was able to re-launch it without any issues.

Hopefully this helps.

(I think this is in response to the proper problem)

Comment: ya i know, found the post to: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/21926 But aint helping tho :/