# the warning "'uniqueIdentifier' is deprecated" in project based on cocos2d-box2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, uniqueidentifier

I create a new project based on cocos2d-box2d, and there are always 4 warning in two files, one is CLScoreServerPost.m, the code has warning is following

```
[self addValue:[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier] key:@"cc_device_id"];
```

and another is CLScoreServerRequest.m, the code has warning is following

```
device = [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];
```

both of them show the same warning: 'uniqueIdentifier' is deprecated

so what should I do? many thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIDevice uniqueIdentifier Deprecated - What To Do Now?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993325/uidevice-uniqueidentifier-deprecated-what-to-do-now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use for example OpenUDID https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID

As LearnCocos2D told in a comment there is also a topic on SOF : [UIDevice uniqueIdentifier Deprecated - What To Do Now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993325/uidevice-uniqueidentifier-deprecated-what-to-do-now)

Answer (score 3):

```
+(NSString *)GetUUID
{
    CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
    CFStringRef string = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, theUUID);
    CFRelease(theUUID);
    return [(NSString *)string autorelease];
}
```