# Substitute for UIDevice's UniqueIdentifier - what are iOS's network interfaces IDs?

Tags: objective-c, ios, networking, xamarin.ios, mac-address

More and more iOS developers who are required to rely upon a device specific identifier for their applications switch from `[UIDevice uniqueIdentifier]` towards the usage of the device's network card's MAC addresses.
This seems to be the commonly accepted solution if you don't want to or cannot use a GUID.
I can also see, that everybody is checking for the network device with the ID "**en0**".
Can anybody answer:

- What is device en0?
- Is it available on all iPads/iPhones?
- Is it available if airplane mode is on or the device is not connected to a network?

I found this question [UIDevice uniqueIdentifier Deprecated - What To Do Now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993325/uidevice-uniqueidentifier-deprecated-what-to-do-now) but it does not really deal with the details as I'm asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is device en0?

Personally I always *assumed* it means **ethernet network**, e.g. Linux uses **eth0** and BSD-derivates, like OSX, seems to prefer **en0**, but I could not really confirm it. That's something you can change in most operating systems (but not on iOS, unless jailbroken).

FWIW other people seems to *assume* the [same](http://lokams.blogspot.com/2010/08/difference-between-ethernet.html) but I don't consider this a definitive answer. OTOH it should not really matter much ;-)

> Is it available on all iPads/iPhones?

AFAIK. Reporting this should be an operating system (not a device) feature and there are no network-less iOS devices (at the moment). I don't have old iOS versions to confirm if it has always been available or not.

> Is it available if airplane mode is on or the device is not connected to a network?

Yes, it's available in airplane mode using the `NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces ()` API. Tested with my first gen iPad.