# An alternative to the device UDID - preparing ourselves

Tags: ios, app-store, udid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UIDevice uniqueIdentifier Deprecated - What To Do Now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993325/uidevice-uniqueidentifier-deprecated-what-to-do-now)

I know there have been quite a few questions on SO about this, but I think that because Apple is moving ahead of schedule and actively denying applications that make use of UDIDs (http://pulse.me/s/7mzKE), us developers need to take an active approach and discuss this matter in bulk.

So the question is - what is a good, stable and correct alternative for unique device identification, other than accessing it's UDID property?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This depends on your needs...if you're looking for a simple device identifier for your application to use, then the documentation on the deprecated `uniqueIdentifier` method pretty much provides your answer:

> Do not use the uniqueIdentifier property. To create a unique identifier specific to your app, you can call the `CFUUIDCreate` function to create a UUID, and write it to the defaults database using the `NSUserDefaults` class.

`CFUUIDCreate` will return a unique handset identifier that is unique to your application. You need to store it in `NSUserDefaults` because it *will change* if you make subsequent calls. For most uses this will suffice, and it's not as if Apple didn't provide enough warning of this change (iOS 5 has been out for over six months now, and the developer docs for longer).

The *other* scenario is where you need to share your device identifier across applications (ie, mobile advertising networks). That's a more complex problem, with a number of alternative options (there's also no guarantee they'll remain around in the future: Apple's primary reason for deprecating the UDID API is presumably to *stop* cross application user tracking).

Comment: CFUUID will be different when users delete and reinstall your app.

Comment: You can always save it into the keychain, rather than user defaults, in which case a plain delete/re-install wouldn't affect it. The only way to reasonably remove the keychain entries for an end-user is to do a full wipe of the device.

Comment: But doesn't NSUserDefaults get restored to a new device when a backup is restored? In which case it's not a unique device identifier.

Comment: How will push notification work without UDID

Comment: Push notifications don't use UDIDs - they use a device token that is generated by the device when the user opts into notifications. They can and do vary from app to app.

Answer (score 9):

My personal favorite is OpenUDID.

You can grab the GitHub [here](https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID/).

I've summarized my thoughts and put a brief description of it [here](http://www.chrismaddern.com/alternative-to-udid-for-ios5-iphone-udid-now-banned/).

Comment: Looking at the code, it just does the UUID in NSUserDefaults trick as described in another answer here.

Comment: @Nestor - I missed that. Pretty hand to have it in a lib though, especially if it becomes widely adopted and we get a standard device identifier again!

Comment: OpenUDID is not restore-safe. If a user restore the device the OpenUDID changes. This make it not so useful, imho.

Comment: Deprecated now see these links: https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID/ and http://blog.appsfire.com/udid-is-dead-openudid-is-deprecated-long-live-advertisingidentifier/

Answer (score 4):

SecureUDID, based on OpenUDID but more secure, accessible by domain only (and salt)

[More info](http://www.secureudid.org/).

Answer (score 1):

One of a devices 2 or 3 MAC address is already exposed by the protocol specification during any wireless communication.

Comment: can't use the mac address anymore

Answer (score 0):

While I think this is not a typical "how do I overcome this particular technical challenge" I agree it is wildly important and could be well discussed in SO somehow (not sure - wiki? Forum?). I'd be interested to know whether there are discussions in how [Flurry beat this](http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Analytics/FAQ/RequiredFlurryiOSUpdate).

Comment: They aren't the only ones to overcome this. I read about several other methods but the main problem is that now we are looking at a non-centralized solution that will be a huge pain in the a$% for us developers. Thanks for your response