# Get UDID through my iPhone Application in iOS 7.0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios7

I have created the application for getting the UDID few moths ago, its working fine for iOS 6 but iOS 7.0 is not provide, for getting the UDID from the iOS7.0 device i saw some mobileconfig kind of thing will work. But I am not getting right to do this.

thanks in Advance.

Comment: This has now been removed from iOS7. There is no way to do it without private APIs and Apple will reject the app if you do.

Comment: use vender identifier. and here is your link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993325/uidevice-uniqueidentifier-deprecated-what-to-do-now . P.S. Read this also http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/182380/163149

Answer (score 1):

See this for an alternative. UDID is now deprecated and will result in rejection.

[An alternative to the device UDID - preparing ourselves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9858850/an-alternative-to-the-device-udid-preparing-ourselves)

Comment: I have found some link those are talking about this but I am not getting any idea from them. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781314/getting-a-device-udid-from-mobileconfig?rq=1]

Answer (score 0):

UDID is no longer available in iOS 6+ due to security / privacy reasons.

Alternative solution: see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9859987/1091539).

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
[[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
```

Comment: This is deprecated for iOS 7.0 I need something like [http://get.udid.io] what they have done with I want to do like that …