# using same authentication credentials between ios apps

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, authentication, single-sign-on

I know certain groups of games (like the "..with friends" games), allow a user to log in with their facebook account or email to different apps/games, and store that user's data for each of the games under one user on their server.  I would like to do something similar, but with no user interaction.  I have heard of a way that apps can share universal data if they have common bundle ID prefixes, but for unrelated reasons, my apps won't share bundle ID prefixes most of the time.  My question boils down to:  How can I have a user log in from one of my apps, leave that app, go to another one of my apps, and still be tied to the same user on my server while using some level of security (so not just using the phone's uuid or something) and requiring no user interaction?

Comment: What do you mean by no user interaction? Like they don't have to log in? How is an app on one device supposed to know that some other app on some other device has an account?

Comment: The apps will be on the same device, no log in view (so the user won't  even know about it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6993325/937822) has a lot of really useful information for this.

Be sure to use a solution which hash's the MAC ID though to address security concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Each app on your device works within its own sandbox. This is primarily for security purposes, as you wouldn't want your Facebook app logging into your Bank of America app and pulling down all of your financial information. Now, if you just want to check for the existence of another app, there are a few questions on SO about that. A quick search pointed me to a question containing [this URL](http://www.amitay.us/blog/files/how_to_detect_installed_ios_apps.php), a blog post which explains how the Bump app checks for app existence. It appears that you need to know the custom URL of the app. Since you are presumably the developer of both apps, this shouldn't be a problem.