# Iphone UDID and google analytics

Tags: iphone, google-analytics

As I heard, Apple is no longer to support UDID (not really sure)

I'm worry about google analytics, as im not sure will it use UDID for gather data for report

if yes, what will happen if there is no more UDID?

Answer (score 0):

UDID is no longer supported through the app store. I've found that various integrated platforms (similar to Google Analytics) will make an update to their SDK to deal with the UDID issue. I would contact them or check for an update.

Answer (score 0):

True, UDID was deprecated in iOS 5.0.

Documentation ([UIDevice Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice)) suggests using [CFUUIDCreate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1542906-cfuuidcreate) (which you can store to NSUserDefaults for example).

A very interesting solution (querying the MAC of en0) can be found here:

[UIDevice uniqueIdentifier deprecated - What to do now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993325/uidevice-uniqueidentifier-deprecated-what-to-do-now)

Comment: um, my question is what will happen if GA use UDID and UDID not support

Comment: Well, for first part of the question: it's true, UDID is no longer supported. As for second part: your code should now provide CFUUID instead of UDID to GA. That is if you're talking about using GA in a native iOS app. You didn't provide that info in your question.