# Getting iPhone unique id as long long value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string, hex, long-long

I'm new to Iphone developing. I have next problem:

I need to get unique id for every iPhone that runs my application.

I found this great project on github:
https://github.com/gekitz/UIDevice-with-UniqueIdentifier-for-iOS-5
These functions return string of 32 characters which represents some hexadecimal value.

Does someone have an idea how could I get unsigned long long value (64bit integer value) from this string?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please note that as for iOS 5, getting the device's UUID is deprecated by Apple and unless you're working on an in-house project, you should not do it. Apple apparently started rejecting apps doing it with no proper reason.

The best way to uniquely identify your users is by generating a GUID at startup. Please see this SO thread : [UIDevice uniqueIdentifier Deprecated - What To Do Now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993325/uidevice-uniqueidentifier-deprecated-what-to-do-now)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot fit 32 unicode characters (every one has 2 bytes, that is 64 bytes in total) into a long long which has only 8 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Luzal is right...getting the device's UDID is deprecated by Apple.

You also can use the **OPEN UDID** for uniquely identify your users..

downloads the classes from here- 
https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID

import the class -

```
#import "OpenUDID.h"
```

and use below code to get OPEN UDID

```
NSString * uniqueStr = [OpenUDID value];
NSLog(@"%@",uniqueStr);
```