# How can I replace uniqueIdentifier with CFUUIDCreate?

Tags: ios, uniqueidentifier

I am trying to activate APNS. Because `uniqueIdentifier` is deprecated, I'm trying to use `CFUUIDCreate` with the following code:

```
UIDevice *dev = [UIDevice currentDevice];
NSString *deviceUuid;
if ([dev respondsToSelector:@selector(uniqueIdentifier)])
    deviceUuid = dev.uniqueIdentifier;
else {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    id uuid = [defaults objectForKey:@"deviceUuid"];
    if (uuid)
        deviceUuid = (NSString *)uuid;
    else {
        CFStringRef cfUuid = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, CFUUIDCreate(NULL));
        deviceUuid = (__bridge NSString *)cfUuid;
        CFRelease(cfUuid);
        [defaults setObject:deviceUuid forKey:@"deviceUuid"];
    }
}
```

How can I replace `uniqueIdentifier` with `CFUUIDCreate`?

Comment: Everything you need should be here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993325/uidevice-uniqueidentifier-deprecated-what-to-do-now. Try more googling next time.

Comment: I already read all posts on stack.. the problem is: I don't know how to implement `CFUUIDCreate` in this case.

Comment: I tried to edit your question to distinguish it from the previously-asked question, but it's not clear what you're asking. What's wrong with the code you provide above? Does it not compile, or does it not function as expected?

Comment: The code works fine but `uniqueIdentifier` seems depredated and I don't want to get my app rejected..

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### iOS < 6.0

```
// Create universally unique identifier (object)
CFUUIDRef uuidObject = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
    
// Get the string representation of CFUUID object.
NSString *uuidStr = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, uuidObject);
CFRelease(uuidObject);
```

### iOS >= 6.0

```
NSString* UDID = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
```

Comment: Is it possible that the UUID i get from `CFUUIDRef` (6BC0A30D-11B7-4A6E-A3E2-763A2F1F0804) is completely different to the one of `uniqueIdentifier` (2f5aa38b6a903303a5bd13950b9c4807bf60e8f2)? o.o

Comment: Yeah it's not going to be the same, it's just guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: This code is legen - wait for it -daaaary.. get your reputation mate!

Comment: @lolcat Does `CFUUIDCreateString` follow create rule.. Do I need to call `CFRelease(uuidStr);` after saving the string?

Comment: you should call `CFRelease(uuidStr);` as soon after the second line as you can (after assigning a string to the UUID).

Comment: As of iOS 6 you can use: NSString *UUID = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];

Comment: @Symmetric : That will always diffrent when reinstall application,
You can use [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString] instead of  [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString].

Comment: @John, that is actually incorrect. As you can see in the documentation for [UIDevice here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006902-CH3-SW49), _The value changes when the user deletes all of that vendor’s apps from the device and subsequently reinstalls one or more of them._ I would say having leftover apps from the same vendor is actually an edge case for most people, so the UUID will change regardless.

Comment: So can we use this Strategy for identifying the iOS Device ? Please suggest.

Comment: @SriKrishna yes but with limitations. In Particular, this ID will change if the user uninstalls all apps from a particular vendor. [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor)