# gethostuuid depreciated with sqlite/sqlcipher - iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite

Found this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555493/how-can-i-replace-uniqueidentifier-with-cfuuidcreate) about `gethostuuid depreciated` but it's not helping me much in this case.

Target is iOS6.0, at compil time in sqlite3.c (v3.7.2):

```
static int proxyGetHostID(unsigned char *pHostID, int *pError){
struct timespec timeout = {1, 0}; /* 1 sec timeout */

assert(PROXY_HOSTIDLEN == sizeof(uuid_t));
memset(pHostID, 0, PROXY_HOSTIDLEN);

if( gethostuuid(pHostID, &timeout) ){
```

=>> warning: `'gethostuuid' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 5.0 - gethostuuid() is no longer supported`

```
    int err = errno;
    if( pError ){
      *pError = err;
    }
    return SQLITE_IOERR;
  }
#ifdef SQLITE_TEST
  /* simulate multiple hosts by creating unique hostid file paths */
  if( sqlite3_hostid_num != 0){
    pHostID[0] = (char)(pHostID[0] + (char)(sqlite3_hostid_num & 0xFF));
  }
#endif

  return SQLITE_OK;
}
```

- I understand that gethostuuid has been [deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS7.html) in iOS 5.0.
- And that the API [gethostuuid()](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-7.0/) has been removed and will not be accepted for submission to the store, regardless of the targeted OS. For existing apps running on iOS 7, the function will return a uuid_t representation of the vendor identifier (-[UIDevice identifierForVendor]).

How to replace the call to `gethostuuid` in `sqlite3.c`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it. Replace the above code spinet in sqlite3.c with the following:

```
static int proxyGetHostID(unsigned char *pHostID, int *pError){
    assert(PROXY_HOSTIDLEN == sizeof(uuid_t));
    memset(pHostID, 0, PROXY_HOSTIDLEN);

#if defined(__MAX_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED) && __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED<1050
    {
        static const struct timespec timeout = {1, 0}; /* 1 sec timeout */
        if( gethostuuid(pHostID, &timeout) ){
            int err = errno;
            if( pError ){
                *pError = err;
            }
            return SQLITE_IOERR;
        }
    }
#else
    UNUSED_PARAMETER(pError);
#endif

#ifdef SQLITE_TEST
    /* simulate multiple hosts by creating unique hostid file paths */
    if( sqlite3_hostid_num != 0){
        pHostID[0] = (char)(pHostID[0] + (char)(sqlite3_hostid_num & 0xFF));
    }
#endif
    return SQLITE_OK;
}
```

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlcipher/_ji0WbDH88s

Comment: Better to change it in src/os_unix.c as the sqlite3.c file gets overwritten via make.