# voting once without any username

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uuid, udid

I would like my app users to be able to vote once. Meaning I need their UDID for that matter.

Since I won't be nagging about registering to my app I find it necessary to use some identification for that device.

I have heard that Apple have deprecated the use of device UDID.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: If you meant `UDID` take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993325/uidevice-uniqueidentifier-deprecated-what-to-do-now/7873609#7873609)

Comment: It's also rumoured that Apple will announce a UDID replacement as part of iOS 6 in the coming week at WWDC 2012.

Comment: There was no UDID replacement, you will have to roll your own.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use OpenUDID
Its very simple to use
You would do the following

```
#include "OpenUDID.h"
NSString* openUDID = [OpenUDID value];
```

Grab it from here
https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID/

Comment: Sorry for the so late response. It's amazing how many things there are on a project that easily distract you. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

As many have said, the UDID block is not the end of the world, since apple have provided ways of still binding to device-specific variables.

I would read the blog entry [Thriving Amid An Explosion of UDID Alternatives](http://techcrunch.com/2012/04/22/udid-alternatives/) and go through what you will need for your app in particular.

Answer (score 3):

use this methode

```
+ (NSString *)newUUID
{
CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
CFStringRef string = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, theUUID);
CFRelease(theUUID);
return (NSString *)string;
}
```

Comment: This is not exactly going to work very well, what stop's a user from just uninstalling and reinstalling the app and getting a new UUID everytime?

Comment: Well, you could write this down to your keychain

Answer (score 0):

If you have time until (probably) the WWDC keynote tomorrow, this could be interesting for you: [The Wall Street Journal: Apple to Release New Tracking Tool for Apps](http://professional.wsj.com/article/SB10001424052702303665904577454653752815434.html)