# Retrieve Device UDID using Trigger.io

Tags: trigger.io

Is there a way to retrieve the device UDID using Trigger.IO? Would like to retrieve a universal device identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have an API to retrieve the UDID because it's [deprecated on iOS](http://techcrunch.com/2011/08/19/apple-ios-5-phasing-out-udid/) and apps [may be rejected](http://venturebeat.com/2012/03/25/apple-rejects-udid-apps/) if they use it.

We actually create a unique *install* ID (not device ID) for [Reload](http://current-docs.trigger.io/modules/reload.html) - it's something we could expose in an API if needed in the future, but it doesn't seem particularly useful TBH!

Comment: Ah thanks for this! We'd like to prevent users from registering multiple accounts of our service per device and thought that locking it down by UDID would be the simplest way. Oh well, back to the drawing board.

Comment: "the preferred solution since iOS 6 is -[UIDevice identifierForVendor]" - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6993440/126600, I don't see any mention of this in the trigger.io docs, so likely no support for this as yet..

Answer (score 1):

Based on the latest [api docs](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/mobile/index.html) - **no**.

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest you to do is to "play" with preferences, by creating and using your own random UUID in a combination with a registration email address.