# Way to get UDID of all devices in which my app is installed

Tags: iphone, udid

In my app, I want UDID of all the devices in which my application is installed. Can i get this ?

Is there any way to get UDIDs ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: what did you mean by "I want UDID of all the devices in which my application is installed." ?

Comment: I mean, suppose my app name is "XYZ" and is installed in 5 devices. I want all these 5 devices UDID. Is it possible to get ?

Comment: No you cant get like that..check my updated answer

Comment: I think People need to specify, why they have go for down vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am pretty sure you can't get the UDID from each device your app is installed on. That would open up possibilities to privacy breach - I am sure. You can only get the UDID of the device you are holding in your hand, or if someone sends you their UDID. However in iOS 6 Apple is moving away from the UDID system.

Answer (score 3):

You can get `UIID` by `NSLog(@"%@",[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]);`

> I want UDID of all the devices in which my application is installed.

You can get `UIID`s by web service. You need to write a web service to send `UIID` to your server.

Answer (score 2):

Use of UDID is deprecated, and replaced by UUID.

If you require to collect this, your app will need to make a HTTP connection to a server and record this information (usually in a database).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean.  Do you mean the old UDID for iOS devices, or just **a unique identifier for each device**?

If it's the latter, see [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6993325/119114).

As I posted in my answer, there is a new [NSUUID method you can use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12670611/119114).

After you app reads this, of course, you would probably want to post it to your web server for storage.