# What disadvantage I have if I track Mac address of iPhone?

Tags: ios, mac-address

What disadvantage I have if I track / fetch Mac address of iPhone or iPad? I just need to know which services that particular user is using. Will Apple refuse my App because of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think apple reject your app simply because of you are accessing device mac address. Furthermore mac address is accessed/used for some times now to replace [depreceted UUID api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993325/uidevice-uniqueidentifier-deprecated-what-to-do-now). You just make sure you are not using any private api's to access mac address. There is a chance that Apple may block access to mac address in the future..

EDIT: In apple official developer forum, this question is [already asked](https://devforums.apple.com/message/739810#739810) and answered. Just read the answer by apple employee eskimo1 there

Answer (score 0):

No they won't, you just need to be prepared that they might disallow access to the Mac Address in a future iOS version...