# Latest iOS user tracking

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UIDevice uniqueIdentifier Deprecated - What To Do Now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993325/uidevice-uniqueidentifier-deprecated-what-to-do-now)

I'm new to iOS development and am confused about how to track users. I need to identify unique devices/users for certain personalization features on the server-side.

I heard UDID is not longer supported, so what is the sanctioned way to do this? or do I have to make new users register first?

Comment: I'd suggest looking into generating API keys on the server-side and making users register by email. Maybe authenticate with a know web service such as (Twitter, Facebook, etc.).

Comment: i'd like to avoid that if possible. users should be able to start using the app without entering any info first.

Comment: Would you be able to generate an API when ever the app if first opened? I didn't suggest that at first because a user may delete the app, redownload it, or change devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[UIDevice currentDevice].identifierForVendor
```

This will be the same across all your apps from a given vendor on a given device.