# On how many devices my iOS app is installed

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

After a whole day search, i'm unable to find a good solution

Apple does't allow to check IMEI number of iDevice

Apple does't allow to check UDID (Its deprecated)

there is an option of **"identifierForVendor"** , but i found it may change if user uninstall and reinstall the app.

My Problem at this time is this

for single **"Specific USER NAME"** any one can install my app on upto 5 iDevices, after that user must change the **"USER NAME"**

my app just ask this on first Launch and never again. at this stage i want a check or Counter Like anything that counts the iDevices for that **"USER NAME"** to check if it is 1st, second …. ……… or fifth. ….

need your ideas or help on this matter / issue

Comment: can app store apps installed on more than 5 devices per user anyway? I don't think so=

Comment: saying five user is just an exemplary value / number

Comment: if you want to save identifierForVendor in it even then its fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i have got from your question is that you need a unique identifier to identify total devices . Please take a look at my answer here at this post i may help you understand many things ( [How to generate unique identifier which should work in all iOS versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17677655/how-to-generate-unique-identifier-which-should-work-in-all-ios-versions/19245413#19245413) )

Comment: what i find is, a third part will involve in my app… am i right.??

Comment: because when you add it to SHFKeychainUtils it wouldn't be removed even if someone removes the application

Comment: you can also save the identifierForVendor in it if you application deployment target is iOS_5.0 and above.

Comment: i don't want to add third party.

Comment: any idea to create my own class like it.?

Comment: Key chain is a service provided by Apple those classes are its helper classes. You can create your own helper class

Comment: my app is in iOS 7 , but identifierForVendor.UUIDString will give me a new identifier if app is reinstalled on same device.

Comment: hmmm then let me try to create my own helper class.

Comment: WWDC 2013 videos contain a Video Tutorial for Key chains you can learn it from there.

Answer (score 1):

you may try to use the token given by apple for APN (Apple Push Notification), it's unique for device+app… there may be the problem that app will ask user permission for push notification, but you can make that mandatory for your app, and let it works just in casa user accepts it..

Comment: than its an optional solution . is it?