# How to make a Label display a Device-Unique code sck as UDID or Serial Number?

Tags: ios, objective-c, label

I was searhing around and i found this:

```
NSString *uid = [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];
```

Is thus what i need? I am new to developing and would like to learn how to use this code. Any help much appreciated. Thank you very much :)

Comment: check the below link. This will help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993325/uidevice-uniqueidentifier-deprecated-what-to-do-now

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are going in correct path

Refer http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html

Answer (score 0):

Do not use this

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]
```

Its been deprecated in ios 5 and your app will be rejected.
http://www.macrumors.com/2013/03/21/apple-will-no-longer-approve-apps-using-unique-device-identifier-udid-beginning-may-1/