# What is the current suggested way to create unique identifier for my app for a user?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I was told to use either GUID/UUID or get the mac address to uniquely identify my app in the user device.

Also I read apps using both approaches are being rejected by apple once uploaded to apple store.

The questions is..., what is the current way that Apple would approve?

Comment: Apple approves e. g. the use of OpenUUID (you can even store it in the keychain to make it persist between app reinstalls). Jesus is much more permissive: you can use anything until it doesn't violate the Ten Commandments.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIDevice uniqueIdentifier Deprecated - What To Do Now?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993325/uidevice-uniqueidentifier-deprecated-what-to-do-now)

Comment: check the date, the post is from 2011, it is not duplicated

Comment: @ThePoet Check the accepted answer. It has been updated quite recently. It is relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this article: http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/04/unique-identifiers/

You probably want to use **Advertiser Identifier**:

`NSString *adId = [[[ASIdentifierManager sharedManager] advertisingIdentifier] UUIDString];`

Or **Identifier for Vendor**:

`NSString *idfv = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];`

Also, if you are planning to use OpenUDID or ODIN1 (or other solution based on MAC address), you may want to see the iOS 7 release notes and API diffs.