# Error uploading app to App Store

Tags: ios

[image]

Can any one please help me with this, i have no clue how to track down this error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you implemented the Urban Airship??

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIDevice uniqueIdentifier Deprecated - What To Do Now?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993325/uidevice-uniqueidentifier-deprecated-what-to-do-now)

Comment: No i have not implemented Urban Airship

Answer (score 1):

Your app or on of the libraries you use use `[UIDevice uniqueIdentifier]` and this is no longer allowed by Apple. The message clearly states it.

Rewrite the use of `[UIDevice uniqueIdentifier]` and you app will validate again, there are already many topic about this on stackoverflow.

Comment: Do a search for [UIDevice uniqueIdentifier] rather than [UIDevice uniqueIdnetifier]

Comment: No i am not using [UIDevice uniqueIdentifier] anywhere in my code

Comment: Maybe some library that you use, uses it. Apple has detect that somewhere in your the code `[UIDevice uniqueIdentifier]` is used.