# Best Unique Identifier alternative

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have heard that Apple is deprecating the udid preventing you from obtaining a devices udid. What is the best alternative that one can use to keep track of each customer's unique identifier every time they make a credit card payment (and protect against fraud)?

Comment: Were you unable to find an answer in the many existing questions on this topic?

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993325/uidevice-uniqueidentifier-deprecated-what-to-do-now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best post so far I have come up with: [can be found here](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/04/unique-identifiers/).
The post discuss many alternatives, the best one I have found is to generate the CFUUID and save it in the keychain. Because its very rare that a user will reset his device/keychain.

1. Get UUID from keyChain
2. if UUID found ok, return back the UUID.
3. if no UUID found generate UUID.
4. Save UUID in KeyChain
5. Return UUID from keyChain.

Comment: Or identify users differently. There is rarely a need to identify devices.