# Find last iPhone restore date

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

Is there a way to figure out, in-app, when an iPhone device was last restored from iTunes?

Scenario: User has data on a phone. Does a clean wipe from iTunes. This app is loaded onto the device. Is it possible to find the date of that iTunes restore, via the app?

I know this might require iOS's private APIs, baseband level log files, or something else that apps normally don't have access to.

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: In your server, have data of deviceId and lastData contacted. when ever user launches the app, send deviceId to server, so update the server side data. The last data means , the last contact.close enough :P

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but that only works if the app is installed on the phone _prior_ to it being wiped. Is a new deviceId generated every time the phone is restored?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993325/uidevice-uniqueidentifier-deprecated-what-to-do-now