# hardware based ID on iPhone iOS7

Tags: iphone

since iOS 6, we used the mac address of the iPhone to create a device unique ID for our app. It doesn't matter if you reinstall our app or the whole iOS, you would always get the same device ID on the same phone.

On iOS 7, however, this changed. It is not possible to access the mac address anymore. My question is: Is there another way in creating a unique ID for each device that is based on a **unique hardware number**?

I'm aware of the UIDevice Class Reference. The problem with it, is that it will return a new ID after the app has been reinstalled.

Thanks.

Comment: > "I'm aware of the UIDevice Class Reference. The problem with it, is that it will return a new ID after the app has been reinstalled."

Why is that a problem? identifyForVendor is the supported mechanism. Sending a UUID of a device is not permitted as far as I know, precisely for the same reason MAC addresses all generate the same MAC.

Comment: Probably covered well in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993325/uidevice-uniqueidentifier-deprecated-what-to-do-now but I'll want a second opinion before flagging...