# How to identify device uniquely, UUID is changing for every installation of the app

Tags: ios, swift, uniqueidentifier

My server wants to track unique number of devices.

But UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString is changing for each installation.

Please suggest for any alternate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25929324/7334409

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to storing a identifier in the KeyChain, you could try using the [generateToken](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck/dcdevice/2902276-generatetoken) method of the DeviceCheck framework.

> Using the DeviceCheck APIs, in combination with server-to-server APIs,
>   you can set and query two bits of data per device, while maintaining
>   user privacy. You might use this data to identify devices that have
>   already taken advantage of a promotional offer that you provide, or to
>   flag a device that you've determined to be fraudulent.