# Device uniqueIdentifier

Tags: ios, uniqueidentifier

I am seeking a way to find unique id when user instal my app and that will not change on reinstall/delete/reset etc. I can store it in keyStore etc but I want it to remain the same in any case. As I can't get UDID now. Which identifier I can use e.g. VenderId, device unique identifier, advertisement Identifier or UUID. Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a unique device ID in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25925481/how-to-get-a-unique-device-id-in-swift)

Comment: Look like [identifierForVendor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor) suit your needs.

Comment: And I need to store it in keychain for getting it if user delete or reset?