# Device Check Api - Unique ID

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uniqueidentifier, udid

I cannot find anything on Device check Api in iOS over here. However, let me draw your attention to the fact that, I wanna use and pass Unique ID from my iPhone app to the server always with the pretty much the same ID even after reinstalling the App. Eventually, I got to know that, Device Check Api is well suited for this purpose for the simple reason of Access per-device, per-developer. But I'm bit confused how to use it properly and can anyone help me with the proper and clear-cut guidelines including both front end and back end parts. It would be great if you help me with it. The Apple documentation link is provided here below for the reference, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck.

Comment: Device Check probably doesn't do what you want; It doesn't give you an unchanging identifier.  It allows you to associate 2 bits of information with a device.

Comment: create custom id and store it in keychain and if user reinstall app you can check keychain for id

Comment: Device check Api -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/44649908/1264893

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked this? https://fluffy.es/devicecheck-tutorial/

It explains the whole thing and gives an example.

**Edit:** But as suggested by @Paulw11 DeviceCheck does not provide a Unique ID, it only gives you access to 2 bits of information (2 booleans really) by device by developper (not by app).

Comment: K thanks. But can u elaborate how to do that Ruby part from Xcode ?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't, the Ruby part is server side... You need to have both app and server codes to use DeviceCheck.

Comment: Cool! As you seem new on stackOverflow, don't hesitate to accept my answer.