# How to "Uniquely Identify" iPhone device ? As UDID is deprecated and UUID changes after app re-installed for same Vendor?

Tags: swift, uuid, keychain, uniqueidentifier, udid

I am building an iOS app, in which there is an option where user can give his feedback about the app. 
I want to know that if same user is using the app with different login accounts in the same device and submitting feedback.

But As UDID is deprecated or its privilege is gone, and UUID also changes for app re-installation of same vendor, So what is the best way to achieve uniqueness of an iPhone device.

I have also generated custom UUID and saved it to Keychain and fetching it, its working fine, but is it an optimised solution. ?
I am using keychainWrapper class

```
private func generateUuid() -> String {
    let uuidRef: CFUUID = CFUUIDCreate(nil)
    let uuidStringRef: CFString = CFUUIDCreateString(nil, uuidRef)
    return uuidStringRef as String
}

private func identifyUniqueDevice() {

    let UNIQUE_KEY = "mySuperDuperUniqueId"
    let uniqueDeviceId: String? = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: UNIQUE_KEY)

    guard uniqueDeviceId != nil else {
        let uuid = generateUuid()
        let saveSuccessful: Bool = KeychainWrapper.standard.set(uuid, forKey: UNIQUE_KEY)
        if saveSuccessful {
            print(uniqueDeviceId)
        } else {
            fatalError("Unable to save uuid")
        }
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25925481/how-to-get-a-unique-device-id-in-swift

Comment: i think keychain is in that case the best solution

Comment: @ShauketSheikh, I read this thread, it also suggests UUID. 
But for DeviceCheck API, we have to involve our server, I don't want to involve our backend server.

Comment: Yeah I also think so @Chris

Comment: how keychain give you unique device id? @Chris

Comment: you just create a unique id with UUID() and write it to keychain. So for that device it will always be the same (except you reset the device)

Comment: Uuid is deprecated so how you will make unique?

Comment: @ShauketSheikh, uuid is not deprecated,