# how to detect whether user had installed this app before

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am trying to check whether user has installed this app on his iOS device before or not.

For example I install app X , then Uninstall it, and again Install it.

I want that app X be able to detect that the device had installed this app before and this is a re-installation.

**Update**

By thanks to all friends that shared solutions like keychain, vendor Id and etc. The main subject that I should notice (as mentioned in comments) is that; Is there a solution that works even after system restore or system factory reset? According to @Andrea's answer using receipts may work but what about the cases that we want to publish the app in enterprises account? Or what if user uses a jailbreak device and install the app with and IPA? Some times because of security problems we want to detect that whether this app is installed before or not? So how we can detect it?

Comment: Man, if it is so crucial to detect previous installation of the app maybe you should consider an external piece of hardware, like a Bluetooth dongle.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe trying to check the app receipt you can infer the original purchase date (even if the app is free it comes with a receipt), but this could be [difficult](http://www.objc.io/issue-17/receipt-validation.html).
If you want to do that you can can add a flag to the keychain. Keychain values persist after an uninstall, but not after a system restore.
Of course this can work only in future releases.

Comment: Does system restore means a factory reset? may you please especify more?

Comment: what is app receipt and how I can check it?

Comment: As receipts are saving to the device, it seems that they will lost also after system reset. Am I right?

Comment: System restore = factory reset, about the app receipt is something that each application has onece you download it. When you delete the app, you delete the receipt, but when you download again the receipt comes back again and since is tied to apple account I speculate that it can contains an information about the very first download(but I'm not sure). To know more about app receipt you can read the article linked and this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Introduction.html

Comment: are this receipt info available for apps that download from enterprise accounts too?

Comment: No only from appstore

Comment: we will publish the app with enterprise account. So there is not any options for us?

Comment: Just a flag in the Keychain

Answer (score 0):

iOS is built to reserve a portion of disk to each application installed, when you uninstall application the space is erased so there isn't a "cookie" that describes when app has been installed.
You can reach your goal in two ways: through the keychain, for instance you save a value with specific key and you check every installation that key or through a simple backend call that send you the date o whatever you want. I think the first solution is better.

Comment: If I use keychain, if user reset the app the data remains?

Comment: Keychain is not depending from  the app but it's a System tool for maintaining values, typically password. Yes, the key will be remain even the user uninstall application

Comment: I mean if the user reset factory the device. According to Andrea's answer it is not presist after system restore (If system restore is what I mean factory reset) so it is not good idea for me

Comment: Yes, if user reset and don't restore backup the keychain will be reset.At this point the only "secure" solution it's the backend call

Comment: So please check my comments with Lajos Arpad. At this point we need a unique identifier. Witch unique identifier we can use for this propose that be persist after system reset?

Answer (score 0):

I would define a method to uniquely identify a device. Whenever an install is issued on a device, I would send a request to a server, where device keys are stored. If the key is not already present in the database, then I would store it, otherwise the install has been already issued.

Comment: what is the identifier you use? I find openUDID but it seems that the data is not persist after system reset

Comment: I have an aversion for smartphones, but as general knowledge, it seems that UDID would be a good first guess.

Comment: Apple do not allow using UDID in ios 7 and ios 8

Comment: I am sorry to hear that. Then you need something else. I would research the possibilities to uniquely identify an Apple device if I were you. I am sure my idea is good, but I do not know how to apply it since I do not use/develop IOS

Comment: yes the idea is good but it seems that in iOS, finding a unique identifier is the problem

Comment: You can get the IP address, which more-or-less implies the place the user is in. And you can pair it with the name of the device user. That is not unique and not exact, but it is better than nothing.

Comment: In iOS 6 Apple included NSUUID Class to generate unique identifiers.

Comment: @HuseinBehbudiRad, to me it seems that Juan Catalan has found the missing ingredient.

Comment: @JuanCatalan our goal is to have a unique identifier per device that be unique even after system factory reset and system restore; as I know NSUUID generates a new random number after each call. it means that is is even not unique per app(not per app nor per device) so it is not suitbale

Comment: @HuseinBehbudiRad You're right, please see my answer on how to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can save something to keychain and then try to read it.

Comment: keychain resets after system restore

Answer (score 0):

As the OP mentions in one comment Apple does not allow access to the device UDID so we need a different approach to uniquely identify the user.

In order to get an identifier that uniquely identifies the user you could use:

`[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor]`

But be careful, according to Apple documentation:

> The value in this property remains the same while the app (or another app from the same vendor) is installed on the iOS device. The value changes when the user deletes all of that vendor’s apps from the device and subsequently reinstalls one or more of them. The value can also change when installing test builds using Xcode or when installing an app on a device using ad-hoc distribution. Therefore, if your app stores the value of this property anywhere, you should gracefully handle situations where the identifier changes.

A possible solution to this is to store the identifier in NSUserDefaults and also in the server and have a logic that at startup checks if there is a change in the identifier. In that case you could update the identifier locally and in the server to provide continuity for your analytics, for example.

For example to check for a change in the identifier:

```
NSString *previousUUID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:DEVICE_UUID];
NSString *currentUUID = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
BOOL UUIDChanged = ![previousUUID isEqualToString:currentUUID];
// Handle this situation in your backend to offer continuity in your analytics
```

I have three apps in the App Store that use this and were approved by Apple without problems.

Comment: does device keeps NSUserDefaults from an application even after we uninstall it??!

Also does this data do not change or remove after system restore or system factory reset?

Comment: actually it is important for us to detect reinstall even after system restore or system factory reset.

Comment: @HuseinBehbudiRad For what you want to accomplish then, you'll have to use the Keychain. Please look into this post for a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993325/uidevice-uniqueidentifier-deprecated-what-to-do-now.  Scroll down until you find the answer that deals with the keychain.

Comment: Sorry man I somehow downvoted your answer and found out to late to undo it lol

Answer (score -3):

You can use APNS. Apple push notification service.

Device token never will change whatever device reset.

So, you can use Push notification.

Push notification(device token) is unique for each device and always will be same.

When app will install save device token on your server database so, whenever app will again install on same device you can check device token from server database.

Comment: So here is a challenges:
- The problem is that when user do not allow to to the app to send push. As I understand, when app try to get the push id, the device ask users whether they allow to have push or not, if user do not allow, then we have not any push Id to save on server side. how we can fix it?

Also there is some questions too:
- Is Apple at any documentations said that push token is unique for all devices?
- If someone reset factory the device or restore it, then it will remain same?

Comment: Device token changes, so you still have the problem of handling this. Please check Apple documentation. On top of that it is an overkill to use push notification service for this, it forces you to declare the use of push notifications and Apple will definitively check what use are you making of this, possibly rejecting your app if you don't use push at all.