# How to get the device name programmatically in iPhone sdk?

Tags: iphone, ip-address, device, mac-address

i get the device Mac and IP Address. But, don't get the device name.

any idea how to get more info if possible like "Network Utility" of device  ?

Comment: Hi Dhaval, Did you find any solution for this ? then please share

Comment: @i-bhavik i didn't get the Device name any get the device info.

Comment: Does anybody have any progress with this? I also want my app to find the device names, like iNet does. I can ping, I can read the ARP table, I cannot find the machine names. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On iOS 4.1+, you can do this: If you are looking for SSID Name..

## import

```
- (id)fetchSSIDInfo
{
    NSArray *ifs = (id)CNCopySupportedInterfaces();
    NSLog(@"%s: Supported interfaces: %@", __func__, ifs);
    id info = nil;
    for (NSString *ifnam in ifs) {
        info = (id)CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo((CFStringRef)ifnam);
        NSLog(@"%s: %@ => %@", __func__, ifnam, info);
        if (info && [info count]) {
            break;
        }
        [info release];
    }
    [ifs release];
    return [info autorelease];
}
```

Comment: thanks,but i want to get the different connected device of ping by my device the other device information not the network info.like i get the my device name "iPhone simulater" this type of name of other connected with router device information. if you have any idea then tell,please?

Comment: @Dhaval: Try to use this code in on device not in iPhone Simulator. When you use this on your device then you will get the router SSID, Mac Address etc.

Answer (score 11):

```
NSLog(@"uniqueIdentifier: %@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]);
NSLog(@"name: %@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] name]);
NSLog(@"systemName: %@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemName]);
NSLog(@"systemVersion: %@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]);
NSLog(@"model: %@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] model]);
NSLog(@"localizedModel: %@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] localizedModel]);
```

Comment: it give the any current device info but i have to get the different connect device in network that name/mac/ip address of that.i get the mac and ip but not get the device name.

Comment: Make this the new answer! It works correctly, and simply. The only edit I made was was to parse the data into `NSString` variables.

Comment: The first line does not longer work (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396187/method-uidevice-currentdevice-uniqueidentifier-is-not-allowed-any-more-i-ne )

Answer (score 1):

```
#import <ifaddrs.h>
#import <arpa/inet.h>

- (NSString *)getIPAddress {    
    NSString *address = @"error";
    struct ifaddrs *interfaces = NULL;
    struct ifaddrs *temp_addr = NULL;
    int success = 0;
    // retrieve the current interfaces - returns 0 on success
    success = getifaddrs(&interfaces);
    if (success == 0) {
        // Loop through linked list of interfaces
        temp_addr = interfaces;
        while(temp_addr != NULL) {
            if(temp_addr->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET) {
                // Check if interface is en0 which is the wifi connection on the iPhone
                if([[NSString stringWithUTF8String:temp_addr->ifa_name] isEqualToString:@"en0"]) {
                    // Get NSString from C String
                    address = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)temp_addr->ifa_addr)->sin_addr)];               
                }
            }
            temp_addr = temp_addr->ifa_next;
        }
    }
    // Free memory
    freeifaddrs(interfaces);
    return address;

}
```

Comment: i have already get the ip and mac but dont get the device name .how to get that?